# Image within <div> how to make it expand vertically without changing div height?

Tags: css, html

Hi I'm unsure what the name for this technique is and it is quite difficult for me to describe properly so I have also found an image that displays the effect I am aiming for.

[image]
<sub>(source: [netdna-cdn.com](http://designshack.designshack.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/FF-3-1.jpg))</sub>

Notice how the cables appear to be over-lapping the footer?

I am trying to achieve this with a small character image that is floated to the right of the footer div, my problem is the  expands the downwards to accommodate the image (as it should do normally), where as I want it to not expand it's containing 's height at all, but grow upwards and 'over' as it appears in this picture.

I cannot think of a better way to describe my problem nor can I use google for the same reason.

I have not included code because there is nothing more to it than simply a footer that is positioned at the bottom of the page always, with a height of 100px and the character image is within this div floated to the right with a height of 150px.

Image of desired effect green box is the footer div

[image]

After following Alvaro's advice I have

[JSFiddle of New code](https://jsfiddle.net/2Z7ge/2/)

```
fake code needed to link to JSFIDDLE
```

How do I the footer back so it is at the very bottom of the page again? Since the effect I was aiming for is now working, I am worried about changing the positioning and screwing it all up, or **should this be a new question?**

Thank you all very much so far for your help. (Question Marked as answered as I didn't want to leave the answerers(sp?) waiting, but still having the same issue with the gap)

Comment: Is the image you used from an existing site? If so, you can just use developer tools in chrome or firebug in firefox to see exactly how that site does it.

Comment: You could have a look at setting the image in the footer to `position:absolute`, and changing the `top:` value

Comment: I think it's much more likely that this ia a bg image than an inline one. Notice who the top limit of the image isn't actually covering anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are likely using an absoluted positioned element relative to the footer by using `position:absolute;` and setting the `bottom` or `top` properties.

[**LIVING DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/2Z7ge/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options.

The best, perhaps, would be to make the containing div `position:relative` , and the image `position:absolute; top:-Xpx` - where X is how many pixels you want it to overlap. 
and then use `right:` or `left:` to position it to whichever side you want.

Another would be to make the image the footer's background, and force the overlap effect by it literally being a part of the image.

Answer (score 0):

Following from what Alvaro said, but also adding `z-index:999;`